# Would currency from another dimension be considered counterfeit?

Tags: united-states, currency

This is, of course, entirely hypothetical. We are assuming that the currency is otherwise identical to the currency of the country in question. While I am open to the legal implications for the country of any available answerer, I would like to know what the answer would be for the United States, Argentina, The United Kingdom, Mexico, Canada, and Australia in particular. (Sorted in order of most curious for the answer to least curious.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about science fiction.

Comment: Of course it would, currency that is not 3-dimensional is obviously counterfeit.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Oh dear, there is going to be strong deflation going into the election on Counter-Earth.

Comment: It strikes me that there was a missed opportunity to address the question by instead addressing how a court would react to this being raised as a defense. Given that the defense couldn't present any credible evidence of the existence of the other dimension the court would be left with the physical evidence of money that had not been issued by the appropriate sources in this dimension. Given the number of dubious defenses that have been put forth over the years perhaps this was an opportunity to keep this one from being attempted in a court.

Comment: Could someone reopen this question? I think this is a case for an interesting legal analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
I would count it as counterfeit as the serial codes will already exist and you are bringing the other dimension $ to this one so they would be the "copy"

Comment: So each is counterfeit in the other's dimension?